# Download a file in xml format in rest api using Java

Tags: java, rest, get

```
@GET
@Path("downloadFile")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response downloadFile() 
{
    File file = new File("C:\\......\\CSVdemo.csv");
    return Response.ok(file)
            .type("application/xml")
            .header("Content-Disposition","attachment; FileName= " + file.getName())
            .build();
```

This the code I have used but When I see the output in postman it does not show the o/p in xml format it shows in generic text format, may i know where I went wrong.
And also I don't want to read the contents , I just want to download the file from this given location in xml format.

Comment: Please describe what you want to happen in more detail. Do you want the csv file converted in some sort of xml? And how do you want to download a file if not by sending its contents? Because what you wrote in your code is that your server should take the file contents and put them in the response, which appears to be the thing that happens. And thats also the usual way of sending a file. Who/Whatever is receiving that response should then take that data and e.g. write it back in a file on the target computer.